# Why does Selenium prevent me from printing the text from "ul" and "li" elements?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver                  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys                                             # For being able to input key presses
import time                                                                                 # Useful for if your browser is faster than your code
PATH = r"C:\Users\Alireza\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"                            # Location of the chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-Beta-Suche")                                # Open website in Chrome
print(driver.title)                                                                         # Print title of the website to console

x = 1 #Debug variable

litwebs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul")                                                  # Literatur and Weblinks body 
for lit in litwebs:
    try:
        l = lit.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
        print("\n" + l.text)
    except:
        print("\n no li")


driver.quit()
```

Unfortunately, it always jumps to the except block and therefore prints "no li" instead of printing the text from the "li" elements.

There is text in them, you can check yourself, this is about the literature and weblinks blocks in Wikipedia.
Also, if I do not use the try/except block it will just throw this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Alireza\Desktop\workspace\webscraping\Literaturverzeichnis.py", line 13, in <module>
    print("\n" + litwebs.text)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I really don't understand this.

Comment: @Alireza you need to accept answers on your questions mate.

Comment: @Hammad I am very new here, mind to explain how i do this? Cant find any "accept" button

Comment: sure, you will see the tick with every answer to your question, click on it for the answer which helped you solve your issue. So how it works in SO is that you ask a question, you get answers, and then you accept the answer which worked for you. This facilitates the other devs who will view the question in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
l = lit.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
```

to

```
l = lit.find_element_by_tag_name("li")
```

**Explanation :**
`litwebs` is a list in Python and Selenium. and what you are doing wrong here is using this line `l = lit.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")` this basically tells, for each element from `litwebs` find a new list of web elements with li. and you are doing  the `.text` on `list` which does not make any sense, python would throw the error but since you have except it will go to except block.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the

```
litwebs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul")
```

Immediately after opening the URL with

```
driver.get("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-Beta-Suche")
```

You are trying to find `ul` elements before the page get fully rendered, actually no `ul` elements are existing at that moment.
Also, for each `lit` you are getting a list `l`.
You should iterate over each element inside `l` to get it's text.
To make your code working you can simply put a hardcoded sleep, like:

```
from selenium import webdriver                  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys                                             # For being able to input key presses
import time                                                                                 # Useful for if your browser is faster than your code
PATH = r"C:\Users\Alireza\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"                            # Location of the chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-Beta-Suche")    
time.sleep(10) 
print(driver.title)                                                                         

x = 1 #Debug variable

litwebs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul")                                                  # Literatur and Weblinks body 
for lit in litwebs:
    try:
        ll = lit.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
        for l in ll:    
            print("\n" + l.text)
    except:
        print("\n no li")


driver.quit()
```

But the better way is to use explicit wait implemented with expected conditions

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this line of code `l = lit.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")` as it returns an iterable. Use the following code to get what you need:

```
x = 1 #Debug variable

litwebs = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("ul")                                                # Literatur and Weblinks body 
for lit in litwebs:
    try:
        l = lit.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
        for ll in l:
            print(ll.text)
        print("\n" + l.text)
    except:
        print("\n no li")
    print('\n\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the .find_elements_by_ method and print those results.